# Where to get large images for Ribbon control

Tags: wpf, icons, toolbar, ribbon

I am trying to build a Ribbon control in WPF. I've downloaded the [Visual Studio 2013 Image Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx). It's got a lot of images but all the standard ones like Cut, Copy and Paste are only in 16x16 format.

Large ribbon images need to be 32x32 (or even up to 64x64 depending on device resolution, [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316921(v=vs.85).aspx)).

I've found several articles on building a Ribbon control and they all seem to use the same icons. Does anyone know where I can find these icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, while Visual Studio includes a library of toolbar images that make it easier to have your own applications have a similar look and feel, Microsoft did not include a very rich set of images in the correct size for the Ribbon control.

So I guess that answer is that you either 1) Create your own, 2) Scavenge the images off the web, or 3) purchase a ready-made library of images with the correct sizes.